# Proving the following limit statement $1/x\to1/2$ as $x\to2$

Tags: calculus

So I want to prove the limit statement
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow2}\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{2},$$
using $\epsilon,\ \delta$ argument.

For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}|<\epsilon$ if $|x-2|<\delta$.

So by changing $|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}|<\epsilon$, I get $\frac{1}{1+2\epsilon}<x<\frac{1}{1-2\epsilon}$ and $2-\delta<x<2+\delta$. Thus
$$\delta_1=\frac{1+4\epsilon}{1+2\epsilon}\quad \text{or}\quad \delta_2=\frac{1-4\epsilon}{-1+2\epsilon}$$
and as $\epsilon$ is very small, like less than 1/4, then $\delta_1>\delta_2$ so I choose $\delta_2$

Is this correct?

Or can I just let $\delta=\min\{1,2\epsilon\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little bit confused with the proof you presented.

Maybe the following proof can help.

**Proof.** Let $\epsilon>0$. Suppose $|x-2|<1$. Then, we get
$$-1<x-2<1$$
equivalently, we get $$1<x<3.$$ Take $\delta=\min\big\{1,2\epsilon\big\}$. Then $\delta\leq 1$ and $\delta\leq 2\epsilon$. Thus, if $0<|x-2|<\delta$ then $|x-2|<1$ and so we get $1<x<3$  which means that $0<\frac{1}{x}<1$ implying that
$$\bigg|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}\bigg|=\bigg|\frac{2-x}{2x}\bigg|=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{x}\cdot|x-2|<\frac{|x-2|}{2}<\frac{\delta}{2}\leq\frac{2\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.$$
Done.